# Upload Project profile image via Autodesk API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I couldn't find it in the Autodesk Forge API documentation, but wanted to see if I missed it. I want to use the Autodesk Forge API to add a profile image to new and existing projects.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Found my issue was that I forgot to modify a varbinary from SQL to a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Is this endpoint what you are looking for? https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-image-PATCH/

You can create/update the Project Image with this.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, now I'm getting the error, "required parameters missing". I made sure my content-type is multipart/form-data. I'm using C# HttpClient to make the PatchAsync call to Autodesk. My form data has two key/values: "chunk" and "type". Those were the only two I saw in the API documentation. Thoughts on this error?

Comment: Well, I got passed those errors. Seems that you have to set multipart/form-data on just the chunk data item. Now, the only error I get is, "image has contents that are not what they are reported to be; image_content_type is invalid". I only have JPGs for this, so not sure why it's not seeing the correct content type.